# How did we determine the distance of the CMB?

Tags: distances, cosmic-microwave-background

The [cosmological microwave background (CMB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) is the oldest electromagnetic radiation in the universe. How do we know how far away the CMB is?

Comment: Perhaps a better phrasing for the question I have in mind might be "How do we know how far away the source of the CMB is?"

Comment: For me the answer is: "Thanks to seismology, we know the distance is ~2900 km". But only because, as a geologist, for me CMB stands for "core–mantle boundary": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core%E2%80%93mantle_boundary :)

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival It's a good thing I expanded the acronym then. Otherwise, the question would have been marked as "Questions about Earth science [...] is off-topic." and closed :p